# Typescript , how to make a function parameter acts as `rest parameter` but also an object

Tags: javascript, typescript

If you guys knew C++, C++ can has different parameters for the same function, well I kinda want to try that in JS with the help of typescript, what I mean is, a function with two parameters, where the second parameter can be `rest parameter` and an object.

So I already tested out code like this;

```js
type ConfigT = {
    key1?: boolean;
    key2?: string;
}

type testFuncTRestArr = (one: string, ...rest:Array<boolean|string>) => void;
type testFuncTRestObj = (one: string, rest:askAIConfig) => void;


const test: testFuncTRestArr | testFuncTRestObj = (one, rest)=> {
    console.log("ONE ", one)
    console.log("rest ", rest)
}
```

however both `one` and `rest` parameters got red underline; `Parameter 'one' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

---

I want that the function with two parameters, where the second parameter can be `rest parameter` and an object.

this object:

```js
type ConfigT = {
    key1?: boolean;
    key2?: string;
}
```

Comment: It's called "overloading"

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the rest parameter type as either an array of `boolean` or `string`, or an array of one and only one `ConfigT`, also known as a [Tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types)

```
function test (one: string, ...rest:((boolean|string)[] | [ConfigT])) : void
{

}
```